# Type Inference specificity does not make sense (How it determines most specific type)

Tags: java, generics, types

Hi from the following tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html.
It says type inference algorithm "tries to find the most specific type that works with all of the arguments."

It gives the following example:

```
static <T> T pick(T a1, T a2) { return a2; }
Serializable s = pick("d", new ArrayList<String>());
```

And says T is Serializable.
This works but I do not understand the algorithm in other cases.

When I try the following, however:

```
public static <U> U test(U u, List<U> list){
    return u;
}

Object f = test("Hi", new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

It gives the following error:
reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that String conforms to Integer inference variable U has incompatible bounds: equality constraints: Integer lower bounds: String

Basically, saying I have to pass String as the type argument to ArrayList.

What is the difference between the two examples I gave.  Isnt the most specific type that works with all arguments in the second method Object? Why is this giving me a compile error.

Comment: In your first example, `<T>` is an output type determined by the common supertype of the inputs. In your second example, `<U>` is determined by the `List` you are putting in. And since you put in a raw `ArrayList`, that will be `Object`.

Comment: `List<Object>` is **not** a superclass of `List<Integer>`. That's why `Object` cannot be chosen for `U`  see: [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: You can add `U` to a `List<U>`. But, if you were allowed to pass a `String` and `ArrayList<Integer>` to that method, then you'd be able to add the `String` to the `ArrayList<Integer>`. That's not type correct, hence it's forbidden to call the method in that way.